# In MongoDB, how do I print all collection counts and indexes?

Tags: mongodb

I need to verify data before migrating to another server and I want to make sure all documents and indexes and transferred properly.  Is there a command and I run to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script will output what you want:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');

var dbs = db.adminCommand('listDatabases');

dbs.databases.forEach(function(database){
  print("Database: " + database.name);
  print("-----");

  db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);

  db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
    indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
    print("Collection '" + collection + "' documents: " + db[collection].count());
    print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
    printjson(indexes);
  });

  print("");

});
```

Comment: You need to run this as a user with admin privileges.

Answer (score 6):

```
localhost:PRIMARY> db.getCollectionNames().forEach(k => print(db[k].count(), JSON.stringify(db[k].getIndexKeys()), db[k].getName()))
```

will do this via mongo cli